# Proof that points change clusters less often as iterations proceed in k means

Tags: clustering, k-means, proof

Is there a way that to prove the following:

In k-means clustering, as the iterations proceed, the data points tend to stay in their existing clusters, overall, because the replacement of the centroid tends to decrease as iterations increase.

I want to prove that when talking about the data points overall, their probability to stay in their current cluster is greater than the probability of being included in a different cluster as the iteration tends to infinity.

Comment: What algorithm do you have in mind?  Any of the practical ones in use takes steps to ensure it will not go on foreover, which guarantees that after a finite number of steps the chance of a point staying in its cluster equals $1$.

Comment: I use k-means and it is greedy algorithm. After particular steps it converges. But nearly after 10 steps the points tend to be stable in their existing clusters and I want to generalize this and prove

Answer (score 1):

There is a finite number of possible cluster assignments.

Since both the reassignment step and the *mean* reduce variance, and stop if the variance does not improve anymore, the algorithm converges with a *finite* number of steps - there aren't an infinte number of steps that could still reduce variance. (Roughly $O(k^n)$ possible cluster assignments exist - that is the maximum number if iterations k-means can take).

Therefore, at infinity the result does not change at all.

Unless you broke k-means e.g. by using a different distance function (e.g. not minimized by the *mean*), or use *soft* assignments like fuzzy c-means or EM - then you do have an infinite number of possible soft assignments.

Comment: Thank you for your responce, I use k-means algorithm. You are right but for example at early steps of k-means the variance of centroids can change drammatically. Can we generalize your solution for all the cases?

Comment: I don't think you can guarantee much except for the first step usually being a drastic improvement.